# Controller ordering in TreeSet to List conversion

Tags: java, sorting, collections, tree

I have 2 lists coming into my method sorted in a certain order (either ascending or descending based on an ID field)

I have a custom comparator implementation that allows me to throw both lists into the treeset and achieve the desired results.

My issue is after the treeset is loaded, I need to return a single list back from the method.  My first implementation didn't care about ordering so I did this (composite is my named TreeSet):

```
    composite.addAll(custom);
    composite.addAll(reference);    

    Iterator<MyObject> anIter = composite.iterator();
    ArrayList<MyObject> returnVal = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    while(anIter.hasNext()) 
        returnVal.add(anIter.next());
```

Once I execute this, the two lists "custom" and "reference" are back to the default ordering.  The Javadocs for Collection's iterator() method state that will return the list in ascending order, which is likely where my trouble is coming from.

So...is there no way to return the content of a TreeSet while protecting the original list ordering?  A treeset is what came to mind because I wanted to use the power of the comparator interface over the two collections to union them with addAll() and throw out the dupes.

Any suggestions on protecting the ordering would be appreciated.

***EDIT****

```
Set<MyObject> composite = new TreeSet<MyObject>(new Comparator<MyObject>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(MyObject arg0, MyObject arg1) {
            int arg0ID = arg0.getObjID();
            int arg1ID = arg1.getObjID();                
            if(arg0ID < arg1ID) return -1;
            else if(arg0ID> arg1ID) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }           
    });
```

Comment: "Collection's iterator() method state that will return the list in ascending order" is this true?

Comment: @Nambari, no it is not http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator() says pretty clearly *There are no guarantees concerning the order in which the elements are returned (unless this collection is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).*

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#iterator()

It says "ascending order".  It may have changed since this is for an older version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there no way to return the content of a TreeSet while protecting the original list ordering?

No, of course not. `TreeSet` is the wrong tool for this job. The *point* of using a `TreeSet` is that it applies a `Comparator`-based ordering on the objects that the set contains. Use a different data structure — how about a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)? — if you want to remove duplicate objects while retaining insertion order.

---

> I don't see how your statement refutes my decision. I intentionally CHOSE the TreeSet because I wanted to exercise the comparator interface. ... My comparator let me identify what components of the object to filter on. I don't want to lose that capability

In a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html): *"The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used."* You cannot pick any order ordering (particularly one like insertion ordering) with a `TreeSet`. If you can't use `equals()` and `hashCode()` to pick the object fields that represent identity, use a decorate-dedup-undecorate pattern with a `LinkedHashSet`, where the decorator contains `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations. **`Comparator`/`Comparable` is for specifying ordering, not identity or equality.**

---

> You're suggesting I need to abandon it and move to something like LinkedHashSet?

Yes, exactly. Either make `MyObject` implement the `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` that you mean:

```
class MyObject {
    // snip

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // boilerplate junk here
        if (!o instanceof MyObject) return false;
        MyObject other = (MyObject) o;
        return this.getObjID() == other.getObjID();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getObjID();
    }

    // snip
}
```

and dedup like so:

```
List<MyObject> custom = /* snip */;
List<MyObject> reference = /* snip */;

Set<MyObject> uniques = new LinkedHashSet<>(custom.size() + reference.size());
uniques.addAll(custom);
uniques.addAll(reference);
List<MyObject> deduped = new ArrayList<>(uniques);
```

Or use the decorate–dedup–undecorate pattern that I mentioned. The decorator class would look something like this:

```
class Decorator {
    private final MyObject value;

    public Decorator(MyObject value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MyObject getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // boilerplate junk here
        if (!o instanceof Decorator) return false;
        Decorator other = (Decorator) o;
        return this.value.getObjID() == other.value.getObjID();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.value.getObjID();
    }
}
```

and here's roughly how you'd use it:

```
List<MyObject> custom = /* snip */;
List<MyObject> reference = /* snip */;

Set<Decorator> uniques = new LinkedHashSet<>(custom.size() + reference.size());
for (MyObject m : custom) uniques.add(new Decorator(m));
for (MyObject m : reference) uniques.add(new Decorator(m));

List<MyObject> deduped = new ArrayList<>(uniques.size());
for (Decorator d : uniques) deduped.add(d.getValue());
```

Comment: I don't see how your statement refutes my decision.  I intentionally CHOSE the TreeSet because I wanted to exercise the comparator interface.  My post says that.  My comparator let me identify what components of the object to filter on.  I don't want to lose that capability...I just want to ensure that when I'm done the final list is in the same order (with dupes removed from the union) as when I started.  If I use a LinkedHashSet, I don't see the mechanism for doing the comparison operation I was exercising with the anonymous comparator.

Comment: In a `TreeSet`: _"The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used."_ You cannot pick any order ordering (particularly one like insertion ordering) with a `TreeSet`. If you can't use `equals()` and `hashCode()` to pick the object fields that represent identity, use a decorate-dedup-undecorate pattern with a `LinkedHashSet`, where the decorator contains `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations. **`Comparator`/`Comparable` is for specifying ordering, not identity or equality.**

Comment: So the error is really in the inappropriate use of the comparator as opposed to override equals and letting the set functions do their job.  Hmm.

If you toss a quick edit into your reply, I'll upvote your response.  Thank you for being thorough and showing me my error.

Comment: Edited, LMK if that's not what you meant.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on this yet.  I've posted in my comparator so you can see how I'm using it.  I am inserting it for ordering as comparator is intending.  I didn't care about ordering before, and TreeSet worked like a champ.  You're suggesting I need to abandon it and move to something like LinkedHashSet?

Comment: Okay, take a look. I fleshed out both of the alternatives that I originally commented about.

Comment: Again, thanks for the lengthy response.  I've got other external dependencies on the "MyObject" so I'd like to avoid decorator wrapping.  Your first suggestion looks good.  I have to ask, though, did you intend to leave out any code that actually adds the elements to the Set?  You need to execute an addAll call for the two collections custom and reference, correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16834/discussion-between-brent-and-matt-ball)